# Center gameboard within box

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center a chess game board that is within a coloured box. My goal is to have the board in the center of the page vertically, no matter what width of monitor. I am confused with whether to make the game board a fixed width in pixals, or use a percentage. My initials thoughts were to create a wrapper that will keep the board centered, however this didn't really work. So I created this method after reading a little on another site. 
What is the simplest way this could be done?

`<div class="box">
   <div id="gameboard">`

^The table cells are below this, but not relevant for my question.

```
.box {
width: 75%;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #3F3F3F;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

#gameboard {
width: 562px;
text-align: center;
cursor: pointer;
padding-top: 25px;
padding-bottom: 25px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Apologies if my code is messy and any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#gameboard {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Just merge the above rules into your code. (You may need some vendor-prefixed rules for `transform` to make this work in more browsers.)

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, it doesn't really make sense to have a large pixel-fixed-width box inside of a percentage-fixed-width box, because if the viewport is horizontally shrunk sufficiently, then the outer percentage-fixed-width box will shrink to such a small size that the inner pixel-fixed-width box will overflow it. You could set `overflow-x:hidden`, but then the text/content inside the inner box will be shifted towards the right and partially cut off, so it won't look good.

If you *do* want a pixel-fixed-width box inside of a percentage-fixed-width box, then you can set a `min-width` on the outer box (a good choice for the value would be the fixed width of the inner box), but then it won't be able to shrink any smaller than that.

Another approach is a percentage-fixed-width inner box. This is a perfectly reasonable approach; I'm not sure if there are requirements you haven't mentioned that make this a less viable solution than pixel-fixed-width.